# Windows 8 Metro apps open into a blank screen

Tags: windows-8

About one quarter of my Metro apps show the loading screen and then load up a blank dark-blue screen. I cannot click on anything and the right-side menu shows but the menu items do not work. Apps like Google Search, Hulu Plus, and OneNote are doing this. I have already tried uninstalling then reinstalling to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Avast installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the **Windows Store Apps** troubleshooter:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185

and look if it can detect and fix issues.

Here are also some information on how to fix issues with apps:

**What to do if you have problems with an app**
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-troubleshoot-problems-app

Comment: The troubleshooter helped. I had to both update my Intel HD 4000 display driver and uninstall the DisplayLink driver.